# Issue in importing Azure resource into Terraform state

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, azure-rm

**Objective**: Trying to import module.resource which is already created azure resource via terraform into my statefile

**What I tried:**

```
terraform -chdir=Terraform import synapse_workspace_pe.azurerm_private_endpoint.syn_ws_pe_dev "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxx--xx/resourceGroups/hub/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/pe-cb-ab-dev-we-dev"
```

**Error that I get:**

```
error: Invalid address
│ 
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: synapse_workspace_pe.azurerm_private_endpoint.syn_ws_pe_dev
│ 
│ Resource instance key must be given in square brackets
```

I referred to some stackoverflow posts, syntax is same. can some one tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When importing resources from a declared module, then the namespace must be prefixed with the string literal `module`:

```
terraform -chdir=Terraform import module.synapse_workspace_pe.azurerm_private_endpoint.syn_ws_pe_dev "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxx--xx/resourceGroups/hub/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/pe-cb-ab-dev-we-dev"
```

Comment: Oh thank you, missed it.. trying this now

Comment: we store state file remote azure blob and i get error ` Status=412 Code="LeaseIdMissing" Message="There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request.`

Comment: @asp Sounds good. Feel free to ask another question about that issue with the state, and be sure to provide the information about the state that is in your config.